# How to link my herokuapp to a domain - www.mypersonalwebsite.com?

Tags: heroku, web-hosting

Recently i have purchased the domain for example - www.mypersonalwebsite.com.
I wanted to link my heroku app - https://sampleapp.herokuapp.com to the www.mypersonalwebsite.com.

It should not redirect to herokuapp url rather it should work as like it  hosted in www.mypersonalwebsite.com.

Example: 
The url https://sampleapp.herokuapp.com/supplier/list must be accessed as

```
    www.mypersonalwebsite.com/supplier/list
```

How to link the domain to herokuapp?

Comment: Read the [Heroku documentation on the subject](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains), it's quite good. If you still have questions, then you can post here if you encounter problems with a clear example of what you've tried and what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add-on like pointDNS and then add your domain to custom domain.finally adding ND issued by pointDNS needs to be updated on domain registrar.